# Input Too long when sending email from oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to run a shell scrpit which executes a SQL. Within the SQL file I have queries which check something from the database and when one of the checks fail, it tirggers an email alert to the id's specified.
My code is something like:

```
Declare 
   numrows number(4,2);
    c UTL_SMTP.CONNECTION;


PROCEDURE send_header(name IN VARCHAR2, header IN VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(c, name || ': ' || header || UTL_TCP.CRLF);
  END;


Begin

select count (*) into numrows
<some sub queries>
    Minus    
select count(*)
<from something else>
;

--if differences are found, then trigger an email.
IF numrows <> 0 THEN
    BEGIN
        c := UTL_SMTP.OPEN_CONNECTION('localhost',25);
        UTL_SMTP.HELO(c, 'localhost');
        UTL_SMTP.MAIL(c, 'a@b.com');
        UTL_SMTP.RCPT(c, 'c@d.com');
        UTL_SMTP.OPEN_DATA(c);
        send_header('From',    '"noreply" <a@b.com>');
        send_header('To',      '"c@d.com');
        send_header('Subject', '<subject here>');
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(c,'brief error message'|| chr(13));



        FOR I IN (
               <some logic>                                 
                 )                        

        LOOP 
            UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(c, xyz || ' - ');
            UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(c, qwe );
            UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(c,UTL_TCP.CRLF);
        END LOOP;
        UTL_SMTP.WRITE_DATA(c, chr(13)||'-Sent by the batch process.');

        UTL_SMTP.CLOSE_DATA(c);
        UTL_SMTP.QUIT(c);
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN utl_smtp.transient_error OR utl_smtp.permanent_error THEN
            BEGIN
                UTL_SMTP.QUIT(c);
                EXCEPTION
                 WHEN UTL_SMTP.TRANSIENT_ERROR OR UTL_SMTP.PERMANENT_ERROR THEN
                 NULL; -- When the SMTP server is down or unavailable, we don't have
                       -- a connection to the server. The QUIT call will raise an
                       -- exception that we can ignore.
            END;
        raise_application_error(-20000,
                'Failed to send mail due to the following error: ' || sqlerrm);

    END;


END IF;

END;
```

Now the errors I get are:

```
SP2-0027: Input is too long (> 2499 characters) - line ignored
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ggg..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ddd..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "eee..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "nnn..." - rest of line ignored.
SP2-0044: For a list of known commands enter HELP
and to leave enter EXIT.
SQL> SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "hfhf..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Oracle Label Security, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options
```

I looked up the SP2-0027 and I gathered that the input line has more than 2499 characters. None of my input lines have so many characters and the total character count on the SQL file itself is about 4000.

I don't know if there is any internal implementation of UTL_SMTP that is passing in some data behind the scenes. Or if there is something else that is happening.

This runs perfectly when using TOAD.

Can someone help?

Comment: try opening the SQL file with a text editor (not notepad, maybe textpad, something that won't wrap) and add some line breaks.

Comment: @tbone I used Notepad++ and it didn't show up any additional characters for spaces or something like that.

Comment: No, I'm saying you might have one very long SQL statement (no line breaks).  Notepad often wraps and it doesn't look that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found an answer:

All I had to do was to split the SQL file which the shell script was executing into 2 files and volia` it worked :D

@tbone: fyi & thanks for your help!